# cleaning problem using java classes in matlab

Tags: java, matlab, garbage-collection, static-members, system.exit

I am writing a java application with a matlab ui.
For this I use java objects in matlab as explained here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f4873.html

What I want to do is create a matlab function like this:

```
function [] = foo 
  o = javaObject('myObject',parameters...);
  o.memberfunction(parameters...);
```

I want foo to behave exactly the same as if it was a main function in java.
So want everything cleaned up at the end of a run of foo, also the static class fields.

example where a problem occurs:

```
first run foo:
static fields are set to some values V
second run foo:
static fields are still set to values V
```

I tried clearing the instance o but this did not solve anything (after a (rather long) while matlab did clean up the instance but obviously not the class fields).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing, you should be able to destroy the GUI by programatically closing the main window and setting JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE. But the purpose of static members is to persist in situations like this. What is the purpose of the statics; why aren't they instance variables of your app or main window?

Comment: they aren't instance variables because well they are shared for all instances. I know I could just give all instances a reference member to the same instance, but that I figur would imply passing a common reference to the instances (in the constructor) and so the allocation of the memory is not in context of that class and for abstraction/modulation purposes I need this to be in class context. I edited my post for better understanding of what my application should behave like and why I pure theoreticly should be able to use static fields.

Comment: Well, foo could exit Matlab when finished.

Answer (score 0):

The "clear java" command will probably do what you want. It will unload all the Java classes it has loaded in.

In Java, it's not exiting the main() method that causes statics to be cleaned up; it's the JVM preparing for shutdown when all non-daemon threads have exited. The main() execution is just one of those threads.

You'd probably have better luck converting them to instance variables. Or rather, taking all those statics, packaging them up in another class, and having all your instances carry a reference to a single shared object of that class.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, it would be impossible to clear the static variables without ending the matlab thread also? In all case java clear did not help me :(. Also because I hide the gui instead of destroying it, I have a running thread(s) left (in eclipse I need manualy quit and in matlab I guess it never ends as long as matlab is open?) Could this cause statics to remain set even after calling java clear? In all case is there a way to end this thread without causing matlab to quit (calling system.exit)